# How to run iOS 8.4.1 in xcode simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode

I can't figure out what the deal is with version 8.4.1

I have xCode 6.4 installed.  The latest simulator versions I have are 8.4 and I don't see any option for 8.4.1

https://developer.apple.com/ios/download/

this page says its available for downloading somehow, but I don't see any link I can click on.  Theres nothing in the app store about it.  Xcode 6.4 doesn't explicitly say it supports 8.4.1 so I'm not sure that it does. I'm also unsure if it's pre-release software because the learn more link on this page takes me to an information page about pre-release software but it isn't tagged like the others are.

Can anyone clue me in on how to run iOS 8.4.1 in a simulator?

Comment: "this page says its available for downloading somehow, but I don't see any link I can click on" It's available for download so you can install it on a device. You won't see any link unless you are signed in as a member. But you don't need it, because a device with iOS 8.4 will update itself to iOS 8.4.1; it is a public update.

Answer (score 1):

Go to, Xcode > preferences > downloads or if you wish to know what version your simulator is, go on the simulator hit home and then go to settings, general and then about.

Also iOS 8.4.1 is meant to fix the bugs in Apple music, so it won't really effect you.

Answer (score 0):

It actually does effect my app because it is useless with iOS 8.4.1
look here for more details:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/SE-JnjXwsdU/LDPtM7GSAgAJ

unfortunately I am not able to get iOS 8.4.1 on my simulator! (XCode Auto update does not update iOS simulator to 8.4.1)